Struggling to Convert Text Hover Effect with Underline in Figma: Seeking Advice for Successful Conversion ( Figma to Code / HTML CSS )


I've designed a basic text hover effect with an underline that appears when hovered over in Figma. However, I'm encountering issues converting it because none of the available plugins seem to support the hover prototype. After attempting to convert it using one of the plugins, the hover effect isn't working as intended. How can I achieve a clean and successful conversion of this hover design?

you can achieve that by using the "hover" pseudo-class. it should be something like the following


.underline{
  text-align:center;
  
  &:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
  }
}
<p class="underline"> Select </p>



is that what you wanted to achieve?
